# Should this answer have been converted to a comment?

Tags: discussion

This [question](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/8512/66-vs-qko-call-all-in-with-66/8518#8518) has a top comment that was converted from an answer.

It was a short answer but in my opinion a valid answer.  I up voted it.

Comment: How to call @Radu-Murzea? Comments wont let me reference him!

Comment: I don't see a comment which was "converted from an answer" (and I'm not entirely sure what that means) - can you elaborate at all to help me understand?

Comment: @3N1GM4 What is not clear about "top comment that was converted from an answer"?

Comment: @Paparazzi I'm looking at the question now and it has two comments, one from [user261490](http://poker.stackexchange.com/users/4809/user261490) and the other from yourself. How can I tell which of these comments (if either) you are referring to in your question here and how can I tell if a comment was "converted from an answer"?

Comment: @3N1GM4 Uh, TOP

Comment: @Paparazzi I still don't understand what you mean - where do I see "TOP" comments on a question? I still only see two comments on the question itself - what am I missing?

Comment: @3N1GM4 The meaning of top - I give up

Comment: @Paparazzi sorry, I'm really not meaning to frustrate you - I see two comments on that question - the one from [user261490](http://poker.stackexchange.com/users/4809/user261490) appears above yours, so by "top" do you mean "earliest" or "first" (it's confusing because you say "*a* top comment", implying there may be more than one "top comment") and therefore you're talking about that comment? If so, how could I tell that this comment was "converted from an answer" (which I am assuming means there was an answer from this user with the same text which got deleted and the comment posted instead)?

Answer (score 1):

The reason I made that change was because it was a 1-line answer with absolutely no details. How did he arrive to that 53% ? Why does that make it a clear decision ?

In my opinion, answers should be at least a bit more detailed than that, otherwise it's not actually contributing much.

In retrospect, there was probably a better way: leave it as answer and comment on it asking the author to expand on it. Though, at the time of writing this, the author never returned to the site after posting that, so I doubt it would've worked.

@everyone (and especially @mods): Any thoughts ?

Comment: This is standard SE practise. One-liners are never useful: either it's a poor response and shouldn't be an answer or it's an okay response to a terrible question and the whole lot should be closed anyway. I would have almost expected deletion as VLQ, the saving grace that it attempted and technically did answer the question.